# Spotify - libspotify error codes

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to create a command based spotify client running on ubuntu/debian. But, I keep on getting in to a problem when trying to login.

The code:

```
int main() {

sp_session *sp;
sp_error err;

sp_session_callbacks callbacks;

sp_session_config config;
config.api_version = 10;
config.cache_location = "tmp";
config.settings_location = "tmp";
config.application_key = g_appkey;
config.application_key_size = g_appkey_size;
config.user_agent = "name";
config.callbacks = NULL;

err = sp_session_create(&config, &sp);

if (SP_ERROR_OK != err) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create session: %s\n",
            sp_error_message(err));
    exit(1);
}

return 0;
}
```

And i get this:
"Unable to create session: Unable to open trace file"

Its error code 26.

Do anyone know what this error message means? Having a hard time finding a good answer for this.

Thx

Answer (score 3):

Credentials are not put in before the call to sp_session_login() and the callback returned when that completes will tell you if the user entered bad credentials through an error code.

Also, in general libspotify will like it better if you provide zero for all unused fields in structs, like so:

```
memset(&config, 0, sizeof(sp_session_config));
// here goes setup of config struct
```

That said, `sp_session_create()` should never block and is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The file paths (cache and settings) need to be absolute paths to a writable place on disk. Try replacing `"tmp"` with something like `"/tmp/libSpotify"` - make sure `/tmp/libSpotify` or whatever actually exists first.

Comment: I've changed the config to point to "/tmp/libSpotify" and "/tmp/libSpotify1" and have the two files with rwx-permissions. Also tested with folders, but still get the same error....

Comment: Hmm. Try passing a valid callbacks struct instead of NULL.

Answer (score 0):

try adding config.tracefile = NULL;

Comment: hmm.... Added config.tracefile = NULL; and also valid callback functions, this gives me no error message, but no code after "err = sp_session_create(&config, &sp);" gets executed. Is the call async? Do i need to stall for some time?

Comment: sp_session_create isn't async, so if it returns SP_ERROR_OK you'll need to use the session pointer to log in. Then it will fire the callbacks telling you if the login was successfull etc.



Have you looked at the examples on their site?
http://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/docs/jukebox_8c-example.html

Comment: ok, yes, that is the example I'm using as a ref. But I still don't get anything from the if case. I've added printf before and after the sp_session_create and the one before is printed but not the one after..

Comment: If it was something with the credentials etc I would have thought the error code would indicate that, but since it doesn't return I'm not sure whats the deal. 
I'm a .NET guy, working on my own C# Spotify wrapper so if there's some C trickery that needs to be done I'm not the right guy to help out.

Comment: hmm.... I installed Xubuntu-desktop in my ubuntu env, and it started working.... it seems the code worked... So could it be something in unity to conflict this?

Comment: hmm... Been googleing a bit, and it seems that this is a problem for some, even in the native client:
21:20:29.792 I [offline_authorizer.cpp:289] Unable to login offline: no such user
Anyone seen this before?

Comment: You didnt sign up to Spotify with your facebook details by any chance? Got a feeling I've read that there was some issues about that some place. Try http://www.spotify.com/uk/help/faq/devices/connect-devices/ and see if you can find a proper username and password from there.